# IMP-00058: ORACLE error 1017 met ORA-01017: invalid username/password

Tags: oracle

Executed command `IMP system/password` with additional parameters from and to etc is throwing this error `IMP-00058: ORACLE error 1017 met ORA-01017: invalid username/password`. While changed the `IMP system/password` to `IMP 'system/password as sysdba'` It passed and I was able to execute IMP but additional errors were thrown. I am able to connect to `sqlplus /nolog` with `connect system/password as sysdba` but cannot perform the `IMP`. I granted even privilges to `system` for `DATAPUMP_IMP_FULL_DATABASE` like `GRANT DATAPUMP_IMP_FULL_DATABASE TO system` but it does not help. Any suggestion what may be wrong? The export was made on oracle9i and I am trying to import it to oracle 19c.

Comment: "additional errors were thrown" - might be helpful to edit your question to say what those were. Those seems to be what you are actually asking about, not the initial ORA-01017, which you've already resolved.

Comment: @AlexPoole there was an error that was complaining about a .sql file that was created an "DDL" but the question is why I cannot use the IMP as I was doing on older versions of oracle. On oracle 12c I was able to execute the command without `as sysdba` and everything was working correctly, but on 19c not.

Comment: The problem has been solved, the problem was case-insensitive option that is deprecated and instead of 'system' you have to use 'SYSTEM'.

Comment: case sensitivity doesn' apply to usernames, but it _does_ (depending on init parms) apply to passwords.